# Query all fields when using single table inheritance

Tags: sqlalchemy

I noticed sqlalchemy generates lots of queries when listing all instances and showing attributes of derived classes. Consider these objects:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(String(length=32), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(length=8))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'parent',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }
class Child(Parent):
    sth = Column(String(length=256))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'child'
    }
```

which I query like this:

```py
rows=session.query(Parent).all()

for row in rows:
    if row.type=='parent':
        print(row.id)
    elif row.type=='child':
        print(row.id+'/'+row.sth)
```

What I want to happen is a single query to the database like `SELECT * FROM parent`, however, everytime `row.sth` is accessed, this produces a query to the database.
Here's the log of a small example program:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT parent.id AS parent_id, parent.type AS parent_type 
FROM parent
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT parent.sth AS parent_sth 
FROM parent 
WHERE parent.id = %(param_1)s AND parent.type IN (%(type_1)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_1': 'bar', 'type_1': 'child'}
bar/first child
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT parent.sth AS parent_sth 
FROM parent 
WHERE parent.id = %(param_1)s AND parent.type IN (%(type_1)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'param_1': 'baz', 'type_1': 'child'}
baz/second child
foo
```

I understand why sqlalchemy behaves this way but it isn't efficient enough for my use case.

Backend is pymysql if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question now after asking helped a lot. This is [in the documentation to inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance_loading.html#using-with-polymorphic). There it says:

> only the columns that are local to that base class are queried
>   […]
>   the [orm.with_polymorphic()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance_loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.with_polymorphic) function provides a special AliasedClass that represents a range of columns across subclasses.

This means I can simply

```
rows=session.query(with_polymorphic(Parent, [Child])).all()
```

in my above example and it will only have to query the database once to print all rows with their child-class attributes.